# Make multiple async HTTP requests with a single callback in C#

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, callback, httpwebrequest

I have a simple C# app which must send one `HTTP GET` request to many servers and get a response from each of them on button click. Also I need it to perform some operations after all servers responded. So, I can use `HttpWebRequest` class with async operations and count total responses number in every callback. But maybe there's a special library for advanced callback flow control, like `Async` in JavaScript for example?

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: @FrankerZ I just need a simple callback library, which allows to have a single callback for multiple async operations.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are also off-topic here. You may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync` to obtain `Task<WebResponse>`. Then call `Task.WhenAll` to get another task, which ends when all other tasks end. To wait synchronously for all tasks, use `Task.WaitAll`.

Example:

```
async void StartRequests()
{
    // start requests
    var responseTasks = requests
    .Select(
        r => HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync(r)
            // you can attach continuation to every task
            .ContinueWith(t => ProcessResult(t.Result)))
    .ToArray();
    // wait for all tasks to finish
    await Task.WhenAll(responseTasks);
    // ...
}
```

Useful links:
[Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx), 
[Asynchronous Programming with async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

Also, I believe, [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) is a more convenient class for making HTTP calls.